# Update SQL records with values from another record

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I'm spinning in circles trying to figure out what is likely a very simple SQL structure.  My task seems simple - within the same table I need to update 3 related records with data from one master record.  The master coordinates are in the record with a class of 'T', and I want to insert that record's coordinates into the rx_latitude/longitude columns of the related records with class code 'R'

The table structure is:  callsign, class, tx_latitude, tx_longitude, rx_latitude, rx_longitude.  Sample data looks like this:

```
J877, T, 40.01, -75.01, 0, 0
J877, R, 39.51, -75.21, 0, 0
J877, R, 40.25, -75.41, 0, 0
J877, R, 39.77, -75.61, 0, 0
```

Within that same table, I want to populate all of the rx_latitude and rx_longitude fields where the class is 'R' with the tx_latitude and tx_longitude coordinates where the class is 'T' and the callsign matches.

I've tried several insert and update statements, but I can only seem to operate on the master record, not the related records.  I would appreciate any guidance that you might offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated

Try :

```
update yourTable t1, yourTable t2 set 
t1.tx_latitude = t2.tx_latitude,
t1.tx_longitude = t2.tx_longitude
where t1.class = 'R' and t2.class = 'T' and t1.callsign = t2.callsign
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0937d/1)

Comment: @SebastianH I came from an Oracle environment, that's why :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use UPDATE...FROM statement:

```
UPDATE theTable
    SET
        tx_latitude = masterRecord.tx_latitude,
        tx_longitude = masterRecord.tx_longitude
    FROM
        (SELECT tx_latitude,tx_longitude,callsign FROM theTable WHERE class='T') masterRecord
    WHERE
         class='R' AND callsign = masterRecord.callsign
```

Comment: Your are forgetting about the `callsign`, but a good solution otherwise.

Comment: It seems it does not work on our mysql 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's `update ... join` syntax.

It would go something like this:

```
update yourtable toUpdate
    left join yourtable masterRecordTable
    on toUpdate.callsign = masterRecordTable.callsign and masterRecordTable.class = 'T'
set toUpdate.rx_latitude = masterRecordTable.tx_latitude,
    toUpdate.rx_longitude = masterRecordTable.tx_longitude
where toUpdate.callsign = 'J877' and toUpdate.class = 'R'
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74db7/1/0) for a working example